# Using JenkinsPipelineUnit to test pipeline is returning error with import in the script

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

The pipeline I'm trying to execute with JenkinsPipelineUnit have some imports and full path classes.

```
import org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager

(...)

} catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {

(...)
```

After I declare the test (using Java/Junit5) with:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() throws Exception {
    setUp();
    
    Binding binding = getBinding();
    binding.setVariable("MY_VARIABLE", "MY_VALUE");
    (...)

    PipelineTestHelper helper = getHelper();
    helper.registerAllowedMethod("getFreeResourceAmount", List.of(String.class), null);
    (...)

}

@Test
void test1() {
    Script script = loadScript("/path/to/jenkinsfile");
    script.run();
    assertJobStatusSuccess();
}
```

How can I use the helper or other component to allow the test to resolve classes like?

```
org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager
hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction
```